# Translation of Proverbs 14:14

Tags: translation-philosophy, proverbs

My Hebrew is a bit rusty, got stuck on Proverbs 14:14, and particularly the second part of the verse, וּ֝מֵעָלָ֗יו אִ֣ישׁ טֹֽוב׃
How do I translate,  וּ֝מֵעָלָ֗יו correctly in the context of this verse and how does the second part of the verse relate to the first part?

Answer (score 4):

This is indeed a difficult verse.

> מדרכיו
>   From his ways
>
> ישבע
>   he will be filled*
>
> סוג לב
>   [the one of] backslidden heart
>
> ומעליו
>   but from on it/him
>
> [will be filled]
>
> איש טוב
>   a good man.

The only real difficulty here, as the OP points out, is ומעליו. As written, it contains four words: and-from-on-him/it. It's possible to understand מ and על together as meaning "on account of" and then [gap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gapping) דרכים ("ways") from the prior line:

> ומעליו
>   but on account of [the ways of] him
>
> [will be filled]
>
> איש טוב
>   a good man.

However, this is a difficult reading with an excess of ambiguity afforded by [gapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gapping) both the verb and the object of the prepositional phrase (*sans* pronoun) from the prior line.  Accordingly, many commentators have suggested an emendation to וממעלליו, meaning “and from his deeds”.

> וממעלליו טוב לב
>   and from his deeds a good man [will be filled]

This yields a much clearer text, and the origin of the MT reading can be understood as [haplography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haplography), dropping one each from the מ and ל pairs. Furthermore, the words [דרך](https://archive.org/stream/hebrewenglishlex00browuoft#page/760/mode/1up) (way) and [מעלל](https://archive.org/stream/hebrewenglishlex00browuoft#page/570/mode/1up) (deed) are essentially synonymous in this usage, making them good candidates to stand in parallel; they are also elsewhere paired (e.g. Jer 17:10). For all of these reasons, the emendation may offer the most plausible reading.

<sub>This answer is indebted to: 
Bruce K. Waltke, *The Book of Proverbs* (Grand Rapids: Eerdmans, 2004), 608 (note 30).</sub>

<sub>*The verb שבע, lit. "to be filled/sated", is being used in the sense of "to be requited", which can carry connotations which are either negative (as in the first line) or positive (as in the second line).</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! =) Happy that I'm not alone finding this verse difficult! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

My Hebrew is more than just 'rusty' **so take what I say with a pinch of salt;** I'm much more confortable with Greek.

So, since the Greek of the verse helped me understand the Hebrew a lot, I'll share what I think is a correct parsing and translation of the Hebrew.

---

<kbd>**מ**דרכיו</kbd>

**with**-his-ways

<kbd>**י**שבע</kbd>

**he**-is-filled

<kbd>סוג</kbd>

departing/turning

<kbd>לב</kbd>

[of] heart

<kbd>ו**מ**עלי**ו**</kbd>

and/but-**with**-on/in/concerning [i.e.thing(s) proper to]-**him**

<kbd>איש</kbd>

a man

<kbd>טוב</kbd>

good.

---

OK, so first of all, you have classic and very detectable *Hebrew parallelism.* Parallelisms are often of great help when trying to understand tricky passages.

So in English we might translate this:

> *The man* of an aberrant heart is filled with his ways: but a good man with the *thing*s [within] himself.

The LXX has:

> τῶν ἑαυτοῦ ὁδῶν πλησθήσεται θρασυκάρδιος ἀπὸ δὲ τῶν διανοημάτων αὐτοῦ ἀνὴρ ἀγαθός
>
> He that is haughty of heart is filled with his own ways: but the good man with his thoughts (or, intentions/motivations).

I gather from this that the meaning, stripped of all possible Hebraisms, is as follows:

> The fool [Vulg. stultus/'fool'] is only concerned with how he acts, whereas a good man has consideration for (even) his intentions.

See *Matthew 5:28; Mark 7:21.*

---

The Vulgate appears to be taking **מעל** as a preposition meaning 'above:'

> ...et **super** eum erit vir bonus
>
> ...and a good man shall be **above** him.